# GPU memory not released after Tensorflow process in Flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, multiprocessing, spleeter

I have a Flask app that runs a tensorflow model, which is `deezer/spleeter`, but I believe the problem is related to tensorflow not spleeter, when I call the Flask API, the GPU memory is utilized but the problem is when the process ends, the GPU memory is still utilized until I restart the Flask server which is not what it should be. I've tried to use this model in a simple python shell, and it does the same thing (the GPU memory is still utilized until I stop the Python process). The single solution I found that half works is to use `multiprocessing.Process`, so this solution worked in the Python shell, but not in the Flask app, I get this type of errors:

```
Allocation of XXXXXXXXX exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

Here is how my code looks like (unfortunately I cannot share all the code):

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def function(...):
    # Call the deezer/spleeter model

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def api():
    process = Process(target=function, args=(...))
    process.start()
    process.join()

    return data
```

But if I do this in a Python shell it works. Also I have to mention that this runs in a docker container under the `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` image.
I kindly request your assistance in finding a solution to this issue. If you have any alternative suggestions, please feel free to share them as well.